# On Fancybox2, how can i position scrollbar on right side instead of left side?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

My website is written in `rtl` direction, and I want the fancybox2 pop-up to be consistent with the site and its scrollbar to be on the <strike>right</strike> left side of the page (as in `rtl` direction pages). Is it possible?

Comment: The right side is already the default position of the scrollbar.  There is nothing in [the FancyBox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) about moving the scrollbars, only hiding them.

Comment: @Sparky : I bet the OP meant `left` of the fancybox ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not work with all `type` of `content` (`iframe` for instance) but it does with `inline` content.

Add the `dir` attribute dynamically to the `.fancybox-inner` selector using the `beforeShow` callback

```
beforeShow: function () {
   $(".fancybox-inner").attr("dir", "rtl")
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xde58wb7/)**

Comment: I still have a problem - I use fancybox as an image gallery. when the fancybox is opened it works, but when I navigate to next/previous image, scrollbar goes back to the right (BTW thanks for the fix).

Comment: @YanivShiloah : can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle? I don't see why `images` should have a scroll-bars since their size is auto-adjusted

Comment: Found the problem. In my html tag I set dir to be "rtl", and it turns out that what caused all of the problems... So i deleted it, and instead put all of the page in a div with direction set to "rtl" in css, and it worked! Thanks anyway :)